# how to deploy spring-boot war to debian jetty8

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-mvc, jetty-8

How to deploy spring-boot war to prodaction **debian jetty 8** ?

Fast develop and test with spring-boot and javasonfig 
like with

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty8

how to deploy war to **jetty 8** version **8.1.3-4**?
how to config jetty 8 ? annotations, jsp,spring security and etc.

no web.xml in war.
no xml config and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can't get your exact question... but hey, if you want to switch boot from Jetty 9 to Jetty 8, here are the docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-8

This will just swap the container at build time, no code or annotation changes are necessary. Everything should work out of the box.